# iOS not terminating app after time expired when using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Tags: ios

I have a switch that I turn on on my iPhone app and when I turn it on and put it in the background, I run the app in the background.

```
- (IBAction)doBackgroundEnableSwitch:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *mySwitch = sender;
    if (mySwitch.on) {
        self.myBackgroundTaskID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            NSLog(@"WE RAN OUT OF TIME!");
            //abort(); //Crash if we get here. (shouldn't be necessary because we ran out of time. I am purposely not 
        }];
        NSLog(@"MyBackgroundTaskID = %lu", self.myBackgroundTaskID);
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]endBackgroundTask:self.myBackgroundTaskID];
    }
}
```

As the app runs in the background, using NSLog I am counting the time remaining.

```
- (void)displayApplicationState {
    switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState) {
        case UIApplicationStateActive:
            NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateActive");
            break;
        case UIApplicationStateBackground:
            NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateBackground");
            break;
        case UIApplicationStateInactive:
            NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateInactive");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"timeRemaining: %f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
}
```

However, when that count reaches 0.00, my app doesn't crash. Apple documentation says it should crash. What happened?

Here is my full ViewController.h https://gist.github.com/RommelTJ/38560b273d4501f81439

Comment: Why should it "crash"? And when you say "crash", do you mean the entire app should terminate? That sort of behavior wouldn't make sense... But where exactly did you see that in the documentation?

Comment: Do you mean it should crash once your commented-out `abort()` line is executed? (The comment you wrote next to that line was cut off so I can't see your entire intention)

Comment: @LyndseyScott https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: - in particular, "f you do not call endBackgroundTask: for each task before time expires, the system kills the app."

Comment: It should kill itself. You shouldn't be allowed to indefinitely run tasks in the background.

Comment: Is this on device or simulator?

Comment: Oh, didn't realize you never call `endBackgroundTask:`... But either way, I just looked at your code and it doesn't make much sense that you're triggering "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler" in the foreground by attaching it to a button in your view controller. "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler" is supposed to be triggered in the background.

Comment: @MikeTaverne On the device but it's plugged in to my Macbook. Does that make a difference? It's an iPhone 6 and iOS 8.1.3.

Comment: I don't know if it would matter. I noticed today on simulator that a timer I was running continued to run for more than 25 minutes even after I backgrounded the app by pressing the home button. Not the same thing, I realize.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes, if you run an app on the simulator and press the Home key, it will continue to run for some reason. But on the device it will stop.